# Compile java using multiple flags from command line or netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using netbeans to get my .jar file, when i run from netbeans the application works fine but when I build to get the jar file I get some errors and the compiler is telling me to use the flags  -Xlint:unchecked,-Xlint:deprecation in-order to be able to complete the build.

My question is how to set them from command line and preferably from netbeans itself. In netbeans I found the line where I enter them but I tried
-Xlint:unchecked,-Xlint:deprecation   and -Xlint:unchecked;-Xlint:deprecation but I got errors, what should be the right format?

Regards.

Comment: what error did you get from Netbeans ?

Comment: It seems like a java compiler flag

Comment: Hi I got this Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details, and this Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. This is why I am asking about how to set those two flags when I build.